# getting 403 error on each service in angular back-end is in laravel

Tags: angular, laravel

I've created an auth service and other services but every time I hit HTTP with headers the request it returns **403 error**.

```
getHeaderOptions(pageId) {
  const settings = this.settings;
  settings.pageIndex = pageId ? pageId : 1;

  let headerKey = '?';
  const headerKeys = ['websiteId','token'];

  for (const i in settings) {
    if (headerKeys.indexOf(i) !== -1) {
      headerKey += i + '=' + settings[i] + '&';
    }
  }

  return  {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      personalization: btoa(headerKey.slice(0, -1))
    })
  };
}

  getCliparts(pageId) {
    return this.http.get(this.settings.hostUrl + this.settings.clipartAction, this.getHeaderOptions(pageId));
  }
```

**laravel route code**

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('get-cliparts', 'ClipartController@clipartList')->name('get-cliparts');
....
    });
```

this same method is working for another project but not in this. I think the header wrong or something else.

Comment: add laravel routes code.

Comment: skdroid added code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using laravel default auth i.e. `php artisan make:auth` then send token like

```
$response = $client->request('POST', '/api/user', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '+$token,
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ],
]);
```

in your case

```
 return  {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: 'Bearer '.token,
      personalization: btoa(headerKey.slice(0, -1))
    })
  };
```